# What's the execution order of CMake's `file(download)` instruction?

Tags: cmake, cmake-language

I have a `CMakeLists.txt`, which has a `file(download xxx yy)` command. There is also a custom_target `cpx`, which needs this downloaded file. But when the `cpx` target is invoked, the `xxx` file is not yet downloaded.

So my question is, when will the `download` be executed in CMake, and how can I make my custom target depend on the `file(download)` instruction?

Answer (score 2):

The [`file(DOWNLOAD ...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#download) instruction executes at the **configuration** stage when the CMake file is processed, before the `cpx` target is even generated. So, your file will already be downloaded and available to use when you run the `cpx` custom target.

Note the capitalization for the `DOWNLOAD` option in the `file()` command; these options are *case-sensitive*.

Comment: it turns out my fault, I haven't pass a condition variable to cmake, which caused the download not to be triggered. Thanks any way, your answer is right.